# To inquire about the query complexity of the following query in SQL

Tags: mysql, query, complexity

I would like to inquire about the complexity of the following example query in SQL:

```
SELECT id
from DB
where Country = "India"
    AND Size = "Large"
```

That is, taking the AND of rows matching the filters for any two columns out of **m>>2** columns. I want to return the first column which contain the ids.

Can it be done in time sublinear in the number of rows?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about the meaning of "sublinear".  The time will be a positive exponent of the number of rows of A, if B,C,D, ane E are columns of A.  My pleasure.

Comment: B, D are the columns, and I want to select the rows where they have particular values in these two columns, as edited in the question. (Sorry for the lack of clarity)

Comment: "first column" -- Did you mean "first row"?  If so, what is the `ORDER BY`?  And can you use `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Consider that there is a column named as ids and it has unique integer values for each row. I would like to get a list of entries in the ids column for all the rows where the country is "India" (out of several possible country names) and the size is "Large" (out of several possible sizes). Note that I could also demand asking for the row ids where the country is "India" and the "Date" is "Last Month". In general, the query could ask to filter for any of the pairs of columns. Indexing each pair would be infeasible if there are many columns that can be queried in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

> taking the AND of rows matching the filters for two columns

> Can it be done in time sublinear in the number of rows?

By *sublinear* I take it you mean faster than `O(n)` time. The answer is yes but under a certain condition. That condition is you must have a [covering index](https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/04/06/speed-up-your-queries-using-the-covering-index-in-mysql) for your query. Because an index is normally stored in a B-Tree logical data structure, the data is already sorted in such a way that makes **seeking** against that index for specific values on the order of `O(log(n))` search time which is much faster than linear `O(n)` since not all of the rows will need to be searched.

For the predicate `where Country = "India" AND Size = "Large"` that is easy to accomplish. Your index definition would essentially just need to include both columns `(Country, Size)`.

But things get a little more complicated when your query also uses `SELECT *` (which is an anti-pattern). If there are other columns besides `Country` and `Size` in the table, now the previously mentioned index definition is no longer covering. I'm not an expert on all of the operations MySQL does *under the hood* to serve a query, but there is a possibility you'll end up with an index **scan** now which would then be back to `O(n)` linear search time.

If your table had a third column (and only 3 columns total for this example) called `Column3`, and you only needed to return the two columns `Country` and `Size`, then you could do two things to fix the aforementioned anti-pattern that will fix the performance to be an index **seek** again:

1. Change the `SELECT *` part of your query to `SELECT Country, Size`.
2. Change the index definition to also include `Column3` on the end so that it becomes a covering index again: `(Country, Size, Column3)`

Either of those options *should* fix the issue and make your query able to run in `O(log(n))` time again.

Now of course if your table has many more columns in it, then the second option becomes less and less viable (because indexes require additional storage space and affect write performance dependent on the amount of data needed to be written to them), which goes back to the reasoning `SELECT *` is an anti-pattern and you should only select the columns you need to actually return.

Comment: I don't see that "covering" is relevant.  "Covering" just eliminates a secondary lookup.  (Granted that is a noticeable performance boost in some situations.)

Comment: I think you have a misconception about 'covering' indexes in MySQL; I added to my answer to try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows with "India"?  If only one row, then any index *starting* with `(country)` will allow the query to be very fast.

If India shows up often in the table, and is sometimes not "large", then `INDEX(country, size)` would help performance.  (The order of those columns in the index is not important *in this example*.)

I claim that such an index is O(M) where M is the number of rows being returned.  And not dependent on N, the number of rows in the table.  Is that what you mean by "sublinear"?

MySQL implements indexes using `BTrees`.  Technically that is O(logN), but the log part is not that big a factor.  For a million rows, that is about 3; for a trillion it is about 6.  So, you can essentially think of a "point query" (one with the `WHERE` clause sufficiently indexed so that it points to one row) to be O(1).  Reading a table is O(N).  Sorting N rows is O(N*logN).

The number of columns can be ignored in calculations.  There is a partial exception to this rule.  Big `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns are stored "off record", necessitating an extra disk operation to fetch their values.  (Hence the admonition to shun `SELECT *` instead of specifying just the columns you need.)

What is `m>>2 columns`?

If you are expecting multiple rows to be returned, you might want to have

```
ORDER BY some_col   -- to specify what order to deliver them in
LIMIT 1  -- to get only the first row ("first" based on the ORDER BY)
```

More on "covering" versus not.  (Aimed at clarifying J.D.'s answer.)

- An `INDEX` is "covering" if contains *all* the columns *anywhere* in the `SELECT` (including Where, Having, OrderBy, etc).  This implies that the query can be completely performed using just the Index's BTree.
- If some other columns are needed, then the index's Btree is used as above, but it finds the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  These values are then used, a la a "point query", to reach into the data's BTree to find those other columns.

So, the added effort for a non-covering index is O(M) -- a function of the number of *output* rows.  The data's BTree will not be scanned.

Comment: Unfortunately my experience with MySQL is limited and my answer is generalized from other experiences,  but MySQL never scans the clustered index when it deems it's more efficient of an operation than seeking on a non-covering index? Also regarding your general definition of covering, I'd argue it's more than just dependent on the columns in the `SELECT` list, it also needs to be inclusive of any columns that table uses in the query (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses etc).

Comment: @J.D. - There are enough substantive differences between MySQL and most other RDBMS that I watch for those who might apply their knowledge without realizing a difference in MySQL.  (Or even between MySQL's InnoDB and MyISAM.)  My goal is to give correct info to the OP, while treading lightly on those who might not have it quite correct....

Comment: @J.D. - In MySQL (InnoDB), the `PRIMARY KEY` is always `UNIQUE` and 'clustered' with the data in a single B+Tree.  (I labeled it the "data's BTree", as distinct from a secondary index's B+Tree.)  There are no "row numbers" in the implementation; instead the PK is used to do the lookup...

Comment: @J.D. - The Optimizer has multiple ways to evaluate a query; it computes a "cost" to decide between them.  It may scan the clustered index (the data B+Tree, in PK order or the reverse (DESC) of that).  A "covering" index obviates the need to touch the clustered index.  (On the other hand, an `ORDER BY` may make it better to scan the clustered index.)  Yes, I meant to include HAVING, etc in what columns must be in a "covering" index.

Comment: @J.D. - A subtle note:  Each secondary index includes the columns of the PK, somewhat like how other RDBMS allow the user to specify extra columns to be in an index without them being involved in the sorting.

Comment: "*...it computes a "cost" to decide between them. It may scan the clustered index...A "covering" index obviates the need to touch the clustered index.*" - sounds like such cost could be partly dependent on if a secondary index is covering or not (since an extra lookup operation may be needed for a non-covering index), is that correct?

Comment: @J.D. - Yes, but I don't think the formulas adequately account for the extra lookup.  (I am looking in from the outside; I don't read the actual code.)

Comment: Gotcha, that's why I think covering indexes are relevant in my answer, re: "*I don't see that "covering" is relevant.*". Since covering can be a factor that decides between a scan vs a seek operation happening. A scan is not `O(log(n))` search time, so I think it's good to note the importance of covering, especially when I wrote that before OP updated his post and he was originally using `SELECT *`.